# How to run a project when another is selected?

Tags: eclipse

I'm devolping an application with libgdx. Because of the structure, I need devolp on one project, and then click onto another project and hit run for testing. How can I remove this step, and just click run on the devolping application and it will choose the project I want and run that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Run" dropdown button (green button with a white "Play" symbol inside) and choose which run config you want to start. You may start anything regardless of what the current selection or open file is in the IDE.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for this scenario?